# HVGA and WVGA800 Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android application and trying with different screen sizes.

Firstly i had tried at HVGA screen and i fixed layout folder and drawable-mdpi folder.
After that i had tried at WVGA800 screen and saw something weird. Devices uses normal layout and high density images. So some hdpi images cropped because of layout firstly designed for HVGA screens.

Actually i want to list my menu icons in a grid.
mdpi images designed 82x71 pixels and hdpi images designed 161x177 pixels.
Also gridview has fixed columnWidth, if i set columnWidth 80dp, both screen gridView has 3 columns but at WVGA800 screen images are cropped.

If i set columnWidth to 160dp, both sreen gridView has 2 columns but at HVGA screen there are lots of empty space.

I couldn't find the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two different folder layout-normal-hdpi,layout-normal-mdpi for both screen in which you can put your layout for WVGA and HVGA

Comment: thanks Krutik, i don't that we can create layout folders with density.

Answer (score 0):

For HVGA use layout-h480dp

And use layout-h530dp for